# Compiliing json-c for Android using androgenizer

Tags: android, android-ndk, json-c

I am trying to compile json-c for Android. I am not able to configure using `Android.configure.mk` file in `json-c library` in [this source code.](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)

I tried compiling using the command

```
   make -f Android.configure.mk
```

Will anyone please let me know how to use this `Android.configure.mk` with androgenizer?.

Answer (score 1):

Json-c Android Cygwin native build

1, get the Json-c code

```
$git clone https://github.com/json-c/json-c/json-c.git
```

2, automake the project
need to install libtool, autoconf, automake

```
$sh autogen.sh
$./configure
```

3, build the android objects
Actually in the step 2 we generate the config.h and json_config.h.
What we need is an android.mk file. We can generate the file by

```
$make -f Makefile.am Android.mk
```

Before run the command, we need to copy the androgenizer.exe to /cygwin_dir/bin

```
$ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$(pwd) APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=$(pwd)/Android.mk
```

then we generate the libjson-c.so at .\libs\armeabi\

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already did as mentioned in this link steps: http://freelancer-suman.blogspot.in/p/steps-for-porting-json-c-for-android.html